# ignore stories.js files from ./src when performing nwb build-react-component

Tags: javascript, webpack, nwb

I searched numbers of articles in google and read through their doc(https://github.com/insin/nwb/blob/master/docs/Commands.md#nwb-build) and issues, I can't find anything. but my nwb build brings in .stories.js files into the `./dist` directory after built. I store stories.js files alone side my component files in `./src` for easier access and update stories.

I can't find any relevant config can somehow ignore the stories.js files in src file so they won't be generated when I run command like following:
`nwb build-react-component --copy-files --no-demo`

Any idea or suggestions?